# showsUserHeadingIndicator not changing direction on android

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, react-native-maps, react-native-mapbox-gl

I'm using react-native MapboxGL.
using this prop to show the directional arrow.
on iOS it works fine. but in android, the arrow doesn't move when I change the phone orientation.

```
<MapboxGL.UserLocation showsUserHeadingIndicator={true} visible={true} onUpdate={(location) => this.onAutoZoomUpdate(location)} />
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you use ```android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ``` or ```android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION```? Try to switch to ```android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and still the indicator doesn't change the direction. do you have any hint? thanks!

Comment: Then I'm out of bullets. You'll have to notify the maintainers at https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues.